# Compression files using ZipPath

Tags: c#, compression

I am trying to compress files from a folder. 
I add `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll` in the references

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\Desktop\error.txt";
try
{
    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(@"C:\Users\Desktop\IN", @"C:\Users\Desktop\test\a.zip");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("Message :" + ex.Message + "<br/>" + Environment.NewLine + "StackTrace :" + ex.StackTrace +
                       "" + Environment.NewLine + "Date :" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

When I try the code above, I got this message error

```
Message :Could not load type 'System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel' from assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.<br/>
StackTrace :   at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(String sourceDirectoryName, String destinationArchiveFileName)
   at test.ScriptMain.Main()
Date :27/08/2014 12:49:32
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Select System.IO.Compression.FileSystem in the "References" of the project and make sure it's version 4.0.0.0 as well. The above code worked for me, once I changed the paths to fit my machine.

Comment: If all fails, clean the solution and rebuild it. Worse comes to worse: close VS, delete bin folder, open VS and build.

Comment: I tried both your solutions but I got always the same error .

Comment: you need the 4.5 framework not 4